# Filter toolbar: data getting trimmed in free jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

We have a data field that is padded to four characters..
For example, you could have "ABC ", or "DEFG".  This data is used as value of a select dropdown in the filter toolbar.

When the filter is being built, the padding is getting trimmed; so "ABC " is now "ABC".. so the filtering at the middle tier fails..   "ABC" != "ABC "

I modified the jqgrid source to remove the trimming, is this safe?  It fixes my issue, but I'm not clear if I'm creating more problems.

```
/* the format of element of the searching toolbar if ANOTHER
 * as the format of cells in the grid. So one can't use
 *     value = $.unformat.call($t, $elem, { colModel: cm }, iCol)
 * to get the value. Even the access to the value should be
 * $elem.val() instead of $elem.text() used in the common case of
 * formatter. So we have to make manual conversion of searching filed
 * used for integer/number/currency. The code will be duplicate */
if (cm.stype === "custom" && $.isFunction(searchoptions.custom_value) && $elem.length > 0 && $elem[0].nodeName.toUpperCase() === "SPAN") {
    v = searchoptions.custom_value.call($t, $elem.children(".customelement").first(), "get");
} else {
    //v = $.trim($elem.val());  // *** commented this out ***
    v = $elem.val();
    switch (cm.formatter) {
        case "integer":
            v = cutThousandsSeparator(v)
                    .replace(getFormaterOption("decimalSeparator", "number"), ".");
            if (v !== "") {
                // normalize the strings like "010.01" to "10"
                v = String(parseInt(v, 10));
            }
            break;
        case "number":
            v = cutThousandsSeparator(v)
                    .replace(getFormaterOption("decimalSeparator"), ".");
            if (v !== "") {
                // normalize the strings like "010.00" to "10"
                // and "010.12" to "10.12"
                v = String(parseFloat(v));
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for the bug report!

It seems be a but, but one should skip `$.trim` better only in case of `stype: "select"`. It will reduce side effects for other cases. I committed the changes to GitHub (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/62294d50454b44b52b88229f23445fadd244dc0f)).

Comment: @RichT.: You are welcome! And thank you too for the bug report.

Comment: this is still happening for me - is there any way to fix it? using  4.15.5-pre - free jqGrid, 2018-08-12